# Separate awk delimiters for the same line

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to separate 3 columns, the first with a single digit 4, 5 or 6. The second with an ID and the third with its description.

Sample input:

```
%ASA-4-105505: (Primary|Secondary) Failed to connect to peer unit peer-ip:port    
%ASA-4-105524: (Primary|Secondary) Transitioning to Negotiating state due to the presence of another Active HA unit    
%ASA-4-105553: (Primary|Secondary) Detected another Active HA unit    
%ASA-4-106023: Deny protocol src [interface_name:source_address/source_port] [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] dst interface_name:dest_address/dest_port [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] [type {string}, code {code}] by access_group acl_ID [0x8ed66b60, 0xf8852875]
%ASA-4-106027: Deny src [source address] dst [destination address] by access-group “access-list name”.
%ASA-4-106103: access-list acl_ID denied protocol for user username interface_name/source_address source_port interface_name/dest_address dest_port hit-cnt number first hit hash codes
%ASA-4-108004: action_class: action ESMTP req_resp from src_ifc:sip|sport to dest_ifc:dip|dport;further_info, page 1-23
%ASA-4-109017: User at IP_address exceeded auth proxy connection limit (max)
%ASA-4-109022: exceeded HTTPS proxy process limit
%ASA-4-109027: [aaa protocol] Unable to decipher response message Server = server_IP_address, User = user
%ASA-4-109028: aaa bypassed for same-security traffic from ingress_ interface:source_address/source_port to egress_interface:dest_address/dest_port
%ASA-4-109030: Autodetect ACL convert wildcard did not convert ACL access_list source | dest netmask netmask.
```

Expected output:

```
4   105505 (Primary|Secondary) Failed to connect to peer unit peer-ip:port
4   105524 (Primary|Secondary) Transitioning to Negotiating state due to the presence of another Active HA unit
4   105553 (Primary|Secondary) Detected another Active HA unit
4   106023 Deny protocol src [interface_name:source_address/source_port] [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] dst interface_name:dest_address/dest_port [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] [type {string}, code {code}] by access_group acl_ID [0x8ed66b60, 0xf8852875]
4   106027 Deny src [source address] dst [destination address] by access-group “access-list name”.
4   106103 access-list acl_ID denied protocol for user username interface_name/source_address source_port interface_name/dest_address dest_port hit-cnt number first hit hash codes
4   108004 action_class: action ESMTP req_resp from src_ifc:sip|sport to dest_ifc:dip|dport;further_info, page 1-23
4   109017 User at IP_address exceeded auth proxy connection limit (max)
4   109022 exceeded HTTPS proxy process limit
4   109027 [aaa protocol] Unable to decipher response message Server = server_IP_address, User = user
4   109028 aaa bypassed for same-security traffic from ingress_ interface:source_address/source_port to egress_interface:dest_address/dest_port
4   109030 Autodetect ACL convert wildcard did not convert ACL access_list source | dest netmask netmask.
```

I was able to extract the 2nd and 3rd columns with `cat rawSyslog.txt | awk -F '[-:]' '{print $2 "\t" $3}'` but the last column has a lot of special characters that mess with the output fields. How do I extract the final column?

Comment: Will the first column ever be anything other than 4 or 5 or 6 ?

Comment: Yes, but it will be a natural number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GNU awk for `gensub()`:

```
$ awk -F'[:-]' -v OFS='\t' '{print $2, $3, gensub(/[^ ]* /,"",1)}' file
4       105505  (Primary|Secondary) Failed to connect to peer unit peer-ip:port
4       105524  (Primary|Secondary) Transitioning to Negotiating state due to the presence of another Active HA unit
4       105553  (Primary|Secondary) Detected another Active HA unit
4       106023  Deny protocol src [interface_name:source_address/source_port] [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] dst interface_name:dest_address/dest_port [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] [type {string}, code {code}] by access_group acl_ID [0x8ed66b60, 0xf8852875]
4       106027  Deny src [source address] dst [destination address] by access-group “access-list name”.
4       106103  access-list acl_ID denied protocol for user username interface_name/source_address source_port interface_name/dest_address dest_port hit-cnt number first hit hash codes
4       108004  action_class: action ESMTP req_resp from src_ifc:sip|sport to dest_ifc:dip|dport;further_info, page 1-23
4       109017  User at IP_address exceeded auth proxy connection limit (max)
4       109022  exceeded HTTPS proxy process limit
4       109027  [aaa protocol] Unable to decipher response message Server = server_IP_address, User = user
4       109028  aaa bypassed for same-security traffic from ingress_ interface:source_address/source_port to egress_interface:dest_address/dest_port
4       109030  Autodetect ACL convert wildcard did not convert ACL access_list source | dest netmask netmask.
```

or using any awk:

```
$ awk -F'[:-]' -v OFS='\t' '{x=$0; sub(/[^ ]* /,"",x); print $2, $3, x}' file
4       105505  (Primary|Secondary) Failed to connect to peer unit peer-ip:port
4       105524  (Primary|Secondary) Transitioning to Negotiating state due to the presence of another Active HA unit
4       105553  (Primary|Secondary) Detected another Active HA unit
4       106023  Deny protocol src [interface_name:source_address/source_port] [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] dst interface_name:dest_address/dest_port [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] [type {string}, code {code}] by access_group acl_ID [0x8ed66b60, 0xf8852875]
4       106027  Deny src [source address] dst [destination address] by access-group “access-list name”.
4       106103  access-list acl_ID denied protocol for user username interface_name/source_address source_port interface_name/dest_address dest_port hit-cnt number first hit hash codes
4       108004  action_class: action ESMTP req_resp from src_ifc:sip|sport to dest_ifc:dip|dport;further_info, page 1-23
4       109017  User at IP_address exceeded auth proxy connection limit (max)
4       109022  exceeded HTTPS proxy process limit
4       109027  [aaa protocol] Unable to decipher response message Server = server_IP_address, User = user
4       109028  aaa bypassed for same-security traffic from ingress_ interface:source_address/source_port to egress_interface:dest_address/dest_port
4       109030  Autodetect ACL convert wildcard did not convert ACL access_list source | dest netmask netmask.
```

Comment: I need to be more thorough with regexps.. From what I understood: the first argument  /[^ ]* / is looking for the leftmost, first occurrence of 0 or more characters that are not spaces, the second argument is replacing them with "" (nothing), and it the 3rd arg (target) is the 0th field delimited by either : or - Is that correct?

Comment: You're correct for the first 2 args to both *sub() functions but idk what you mean by `the 0th field` - are you referring to the call to `gensub()` or to `sub()`?

Comment: I'm referring to sub(), when you initalized x = $0

Comment: `$0` is the current record (a line in your case), not any of the fields of the record, so `x=$0` is saving the current line in `x` and then `sub(/[^ ]* /,"",x)` removes the string that matches ```[^ ]* ``` (i.e. the first string of non-blanks followed by a blank such as ```%ASA-4-105505: ```) from the front of `x` thereby just leaving everything after the first blank in `x` so after the `sub()` x contains `(Primary|Secondary) Failed to connect to peer unit peer-ip:port`. You could add `print x` statements to the code to see what `x` contains at each step.

Comment: That's succinct. So a copy of the current record is trimmed to include everything after the first blank space, stores that in `x`, and then `print` just puts it all in one line. Thanks for this!

Comment: To be clear: not the current record, the contents of `x` which is a copy of the current record. If I trimmed the current record (`$0`) then I'd no longer have `$2` and `$3` available for printing which is why I'm saving a copy of the current record, `$0`, in `x` and then trimming `x` instead of trimming `$0`. I could alternatively have done `y=$2; z=$3; sub(/[^ ]* /,""); print y, z, $0` which WOULD be trimming the current record (the default 3rd arg for sub() is `$0`).

Answer (score 2):

A Perl approach:

```
$ perl -lne 'print join "\t",$1,$2,$3 if /-(\d)-(\d+):\s+(.*)/' file 
4   105505  (Primary|Secondary) Failed to connect to peer unit peer-ip:port    
4   105524  (Primary|Secondary) Transitioning to Negotiating state due to the presence of another Active HA unit    
4   105553  (Primary|Secondary) Detected another Active HA unit    
4   106023  Deny protocol src [interface_name:source_address/source_port] [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] dst interface_name:dest_address/dest_port [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] [type {string}, code {code}] by access_group acl_ID [0x8ed66b60, 0xf8852875]
4   106027  Deny src [source address] dst [destination address] by access-group “access-list name”.
4   106103  access-list acl_ID denied protocol for user username interface_name/source_address source_port interface_name/dest_address dest_port hit-cnt number first hit hash codes
4   108004  action_class: action ESMTP req_resp from src_ifc:sip|sport to dest_ifc:dip|dport;further_info, page 1-23
4   109017  User at IP_address exceeded auth proxy connection limit (max)
4   109022  exceeded HTTPS proxy process limit
4   109027  [aaa protocol] Unable to decipher response message Server = server_IP_address, User = user
4   109028  aaa bypassed for same-security traffic from ingress_ interface:source_address/source_port to egress_interface:dest_address/dest_port
4   109030  Autodetect ACL convert wildcard did not convert ACL access_list source | dest netmask netmask.
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne 'put ($0,$1,$2).join("\t") if / \- (<[456]>) \- (\d+) \: \s+ (.*) /;'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne '.split(/<[:-]>/, 4).skip.join("\t").put;'
```

The first answer generally follows @terdon's Perl5 code, while the second answer generally follows @glenn_jackman's Perl5 code.

Note in Raku:

1. Raku captures start from `$0`,
2. Raku doesn't make you guess when escaping characters within regexes: if it isn't `<alnum>` it needs to be escaped,
3. Enumerated character classes are created in Raku with `<[` ... `]>`,
4. A leading `.` (like `.split`) is short for `$_.`, indicating the
   function call applies to the `$_` topic variable.

Sample Input:

```
%ASA-4-105505: (Primary|Secondary) Failed to connect to peer unit peer-ip:port    
%ASA-4-105524: (Primary|Secondary) Transitioning to Negotiating state due to the presence of another Active HA unit    
%ASA-4-105553: (Primary|Secondary) Detected another Active HA unit    
%ASA-4-106023: Deny protocol src [interface_name:source_address/source_port] [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] dst interface_name:dest_address/dest_port [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] [type {string}, code {code}] by access_group acl_ID [0x8ed66b60, 0xf8852875]
%ASA-4-106027: Deny src [source address] dst [destination address] by access-group “access-list name”.
%ASA-4-106103: access-list acl_ID denied protocol for user username interface_name/source_address source_port interface_name/dest_address dest_port hit-cnt number first hit hash codes
%ASA-4-108004: action_class: action ESMTP req_resp from src_ifc:sip|sport to dest_ifc:dip|dport;further_info, page 1-23
%ASA-4-109017: User at IP_address exceeded auth proxy connection limit (max)
%ASA-4-109022: exceeded HTTPS proxy process limit
%ASA-4-109027: [aaa protocol] Unable to decipher response message Server = server_IP_address, User = user
%ASA-4-109028: aaa bypassed for same-security traffic from ingress_ interface:source_address/source_port to egress_interface:dest_address/dest_port
%ASA-4-109030: Autodetect ACL convert wildcard did not convert ACL access_list source | dest netmask netmask.
```

Sample Output:

```
4   105505   (Primary|Secondary) Failed to connect to peer unit peer-ip:port    
4   105524   (Primary|Secondary) Transitioning to Negotiating state due to the presence of another Active HA unit    
4   105553   (Primary|Secondary) Detected another Active HA unit    
4   106023   Deny protocol src [interface_name:source_address/source_port] [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] dst interface_name:dest_address/dest_port [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] [type {string}, code {code}] by access_group acl_ID [0x8ed66b60, 0xf8852875]
4   106027   Deny src [source address] dst [destination address] by access-group “access-list name”.
4   106103   access-list acl_ID denied protocol for user username interface_name/source_address source_port interface_name/dest_address dest_port hit-cnt number first hit hash codes
4   108004   action_class: action ESMTP req_resp from src_ifc:sip|sport to dest_ifc:dip|dport;further_info, page 1-23
4   109017   User at IP_address exceeded auth proxy connection limit (max)
4   109022   exceeded HTTPS proxy process limit
4   109027   [aaa protocol] Unable to decipher response message Server = server_IP_address, User = user
4   109028   aaa bypassed for same-security traffic from ingress_ interface:source_address/source_port to egress_interface:dest_address/dest_port
4   109030   Autodetect ACL convert wildcard did not convert ACL access_list source | dest netmask netmask.
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

I was able to split on `-` as field separator and then, using `index` and `substr` functions as follows"

```
awk -F '-' '{i=index($3,":"); print $2 "\t" substr($3,1,i-1) "\t" substr($3,i+1)}'
```

Comment: This works for the most part, but messes up descriptions with a - in them

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```bsh
$ sed 's/^.\{5\}\([[:digit:]]\+\)-\([[:digit:]]\+\):[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)$/\1\t\2\t\3/' file 
4       105505  (Primary|Secondary) Failed to connect to peer unit peer-ip:port
4       105524  (Primary|Secondary) Transitioning to Negotiating state due to the presence of another Active HA unit
4       105553  (Primary|Secondary) Detected another Active HA unit
4       106023  Deny protocol src [interface_name:source_address/source_port] [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] dst interface_name:dest_address/dest_port [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] [type {string}, code {code}] by access_group acl_ID [0x8ed66b60, 0xf8852875]
4       106027  Deny src [source address] dst [destination address] by access-group “access-list name”.
4       106103  access-list acl_ID denied protocol for user username interface_name/source_address source_port interface_name/dest_address dest_port hit-cnt number first hit hash codes
4       108004  action_class: action ESMTP req_resp from src_ifc:sip|sport to dest_ifc:dip|dport;further_info, page 1-23
4       109017  User at IP_address exceeded auth proxy connection limit (max)
4       109022  exceeded HTTPS proxy process limit
4       109027  [aaa protocol] Unable to decipher response message Server = server_IP_address, User = user
4       109028  aaa bypassed for same-security traffic from ingress_ interface:source_address/source_port to egress_interface:dest_address/dest_port
4       109030  Autodetect ACL convert wildcard did not convert ACL access_list source | dest netmask netmask.
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk, we can use the 3-argument `match` function:

```bsh
gawk -v OFS='\t' '
    match($0, /-([456])-([^:]+): (.*)/, m) {print m[1], m[2], m[3]}
' file
```

See [String Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) in the manual

---

Or perl where we can set an upper limit for how many pieces the `split` function returns:

```bsh
perl -ne '
    @fields = split(/[:-]/, $_, 4);
    shift @fields;
    print join "\t", @fields;
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\)-\([^:]*\):/\1 \2/' file
4 105505 (Primary|Secondary) Failed to connect to peer unit peer-ip:port
4 105524 (Primary|Secondary) Transitioning to Negotiating state due to the presence of another Active HA unit
4 105553 (Primary|Secondary) Detected another Active HA unit
4 106023 Deny protocol src [interface_name:source_address/source_port] [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] dst interface_name:dest_address/dest_port [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] [type {string}, code {code}] by access_group acl_ID [0x8ed66b60, 0xf8852875]
```

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F: 'BEGIN{OFS=""}{sub(/%ASA-/,"",$1);sub(/-/," ",$1)}1' file
4 105505 (Primary|Secondary) Failed to connect to peer unit peer-ipport
4 105524 (Primary|Secondary) Transitioning to Negotiating state due to the presence of another Active HA unit
4 105553 (Primary|Secondary) Detected another Active HA unit
4 106023 Deny protocol src [interface_namesource_address/source_port] [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] dst interface_namedest_address/dest_port [([idfw_user|FQDN_string], sg_info)] [type {string}, code {code}] by access_group acl_ID [0x8ed66b60, 0xf8852875]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use other awk functions to separate data. Perhaps:

```
awk '
NF {
    j = index ($0, ": ");
    split (substr ($0, 1, j - 1), V, "-");
    printf ("%s   %s %s\n", V[2], V[3], substr ($0, j + 2));
}' rawSyslog.txt
```

It assumes your input data is reliable, but ignores the blank lines. I used spaces for the output separators, but you may have intended tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Split it in two chunk the first from the `%` character up to the `:` character, and the second anythings comes after.
Then the first field will be `split`ted again at each `-` to get the digit and the id.
The second chunk will be reassamble in the for loop if another occurence of the `FS` is encounterd.
If you are sure that no occurence of `FS` can occur you can omi the for loop and just print `a[2], a[3], $2`.

```
awk -F': ' -v OFS='\t' '{
    split($1, a, "-")
    s = ""
    for(i = 2; i <= NF; i++) 
        s = s ? s FS $i : $i
    print a[2], a[3], s
}' test
```